# How to have a child link with two parent links for URDF

Tags: gazebo, urdf, robot, robot-model, linking

As the title states, there is a link on my robot that is connected to two different parent links in seperate places. I don't know how to do this as it says that every single link must be unique. Is there a way to do this in URDF or do I need to use SDF?